# Regex to replace JavaScript comments with Grails comments

Tags: javascript, regex, grails

I have the goal of removing all the JavaScript comments that get rendered out to HTML.

In Grails, you can use <%-- comment --%> style comments that will not end up in the HTML output, so I'm trying to come up with an expression I can use to match any JS comments. The problem I'm having is that some comments are already wrapped in <%-- --%>

I can use regex with a negative look behind like:

```
 (?<!<%-- )//(.*)
```

to skip selecting something like:

```
 <%-- // some comment --%>
```

but I need there to be an arbitrary amount (including none) whitespace between the <%-- and //

For example, the regex needs to also skip:

```
 <%--// some comment --%>
 <%--     // some comment --%>
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this? I admit that I am a bit of an amateur when it comes to regular expressions.

I read somewhere that \s* can be used for optional white space characters, but I can't seem to figure out the proper syntax to make it work using this as part of the look behind (or if that is possible?)

Comment: I may be missing something, but, Why don't you just replace `<!--` with `<%--` and `-->` with `--%>` using two replaces?

Comment: @Racso JavaScript comment != HTML comment.

Answer (score 0):

Your \s* idea inside a lookbehind does not work because in most (if not all) GREP versions, you cannot use a lookbehind of variable length.

Is a two-step version also okay?

1. remove previous nested comment starts: replace <%--\s*// with <%--
2. convert remaining //comments as you already did to your Grails notation.

(Edit)

Ah, the wonders of GREP. After a bit of lateral thinking:

Search for

```
(<%--\s*)?//\s*(.+?)(\s*--%>)?$
```

Replace with

```
<%-- \2 --%>
```

This assumes your GREP dialect understands the non-greedy modifier expression (.+?) -- it is necessary in this case to prevent gobbling up the end sequence "--%>" (which, after all, is optional), and doubling it in the output.

If it does not, try this:

```
(<%--\s*)?//\s*(((?!--%>).)*)(--%>)?
```

replace with the same.